# Getting weird resitance drops with an FSR and a raspi using a MCP30

Tags: raspberry-pi, voltage-divider, microchip

I tried to create a weight detecting device, that detects when a heavy objects are placed on a table. Its supposed to work like this:

[image]

The raspi keeps checking the recistance on the force sensing resitor (fsr) using a mcp3008 ADC (not pictured)
Once the heavy object is placed on the table, the FSR detects the shift in resitance and adds an entry in the database along with the date, and the same thing happens if the object is removed again.

I managed to hook up the FSR and the MCP3008 using this graph :

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpX9iG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

but after letting it run for a while  without putting any weight on it, this happened (10 minutes from left to right):

[image]

the voltage drops, resurfaces and then slowly swindles down again (notice the graph only goes to 1.48V)
when a heavy objects is placed on the FSR, it goes to about 1.58V, when its empty state is 1.68V, so this is a problem.

Does anybody have any idea, what could cause this? It seams to be stable for a few minutes but then it just drops.
Excel:

https://pastebin.com/raw/kjntnpin

Edit: i tried again but now the bahviour is even weirder (again, I didn't change the weight, I just let it sit for 20 minutes), it looks like a pattern and just seams to smooth out after a while, which is especially strange:

[image]

another stat, this time from 21:00PM to  8:30AM, with a heavy object on the FSR from 22:00 PM until 6:50

[image]

Comment: Could you show a schematic of exactly how you're measuring the resistance?

Comment: not sure what you mean, but I clarified how the MCP3008 is used

Comment: So you're using it as one leg of a voltage divider. That'll work, but wouldn't be my choice. What's your power source?

Comment: the entire circuit runs on the 3.3V port of the raspbi, since the tekscan (FSR) website says to use a low drive voltage for big loads. Also I can't see how else I'm supposed to measure its resistance, since even a multimeter needs to run a current through a to measure it. What would you have done?

Comment: I would have used a constant current source to drive current through it, and a buffer amplifier afterward. But you didn't answer my question: what's your power source?

Comment: the 3.3 V GPIO pin on the raspberry pi, which is connected to my wall socket over a phone charger, which is hooked to the power grid. Should I try swapping it with another charger? Also isn't the raspi a constant power source? Also is a buffer amplifier really necessary for measuring resitance?

Comment: Use a multimeter rather than the ADC to measure the voltage from your voltage divider and repeat your tests...figure out where the problem lies. Also, add a link to the datasheet for the FSR to your question.

Comment: , ill try that tomorrow and I'll link the datasheet right now

Comment: Powering something from a gpio pin is not recommended.

Comment: Please expand the acronym "FSR" and tell us who don't know exactly what it is.

Comment: It's probably the 3v3 rail not the gpio, but it's still a bad idea as the pi is very sensitive to disturbance there, and it's likely noisy too.

Comment: Yes sorry, its a texcan force sensing resistor a502

Comment: @chris, so do you think the 5V pin would be better? Or should I break a usb cable and connect it to its 5v?

Comment: Regulating your own supply from the 5v rail would be better, yes.

Comment: By 5V rail you mean gpio pin, right? And should I maybe use one pin for reference voltage and another for the voltage divider? Or do you mean I should hook it up to its own 5V supply?

Comment: The pi's 5v rail is present on the "GPIO header" but it is a not a "GPIO pin" - it is a supply pin, not an I/O pin.  That said, you may not be going about this project in a way which will yield success.  Using an everyday scale on the table would be simpler, and you can rip out the existing electronics and feed the load cell into an HX711 if you prefer.  Or you can instrument each leg of the table.

Comment: I would disagree, since I don't think the voltage drop can hardly be the fault of the FSR, since its resistance is constant (I checked 5 min with a multimeter) and as you can see in the picture from 9pm to 8:30am, it has no problem detecting a the shift in weight. theres probably some voltage drop on the raspberry. I tried load cells already, but the ones I bought for 30$ just stopped working altogether under high enough pressure and better ones cost around 100$ and I'm probably gonna need a lot of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the change (drift) in voltage is pretty slow, maybe due to temperature changes in/at the resistors?

An easy (software) solution is to take the differential of the voltage over time and compare that value to a threshold.

In other words, compare each sample taken to the one before, and if the difference between them is, say, > 20% you have detected a significant change (i.e. object put onto/removed from the table).

To suppress more noise, you may want to vary the scheme by, e.g., having a running average of the last n samples and compare each new sample to that average; or have two running averages, one of the samples n...m and the other one of m+1...current and compare those. This averaging basically creates a low-pass filter and the window sizes should be chosen so as to suppress as much noise as possible while still giving a useful amplitude for your signal.

Comment: I was thinking that too,  although the problem is, that the last chart that shows the last valley has a very significant weight shift (10kg table, 50kg object), so a with 10kg item for example it becomes difficult to differentiate between drift and weight change